# Understanding how to sort 2-d array using Arrays.sort() and Integer.compare()

Tags: java, sorting

I was doing a leetcode problem where a user was sorting a 2-D array using `Arrays.sort(intervals, (a,b)->Integer.compare(a[0],b[0]));`

Now, I understand to some extent what is happening here. The `sort()` method consults `compare()` every time it has to compare the integers.

Now my question is how does the sort function know how to interpret the result of the lamda expression: `(a,b)->Integer.compare(a[0],b[0])`, as it only returns 1,0,-1 depending on the input.

Would really help if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Negative means a<b. Positive means a>b. Zero means a=b. See the docs for [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#:~:text=Returns%20a%20negative%20integer%2C%20zero%2C%20or%20a%20positive%20integer%20as%20the%20first%20argument%20is%20less%20than%2C%20equal%20to%2C%20or%20greater%20than%20the%20second.).

Comment: `1` means greater than, `-1` means less than and `0` means equal to. That is generally how sort works in Java. You compare two values. Those are the only three possible results of comparing two values.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What I meant was how does the sort() function know what 1,-1 and 0 mean respectively ?

Comment: Because it was programmed to know. Assuming you have a `Comparator c` then `c.compare(a,b)` will return one of those values (as discussed), then you use the result of the comparison to do the sorting (instead of `if (a < b)` you have `if (c.compare(a,b) < 0)` which means the same thing but allows you to have any kind of logic to determine that `a` is less than `b`).